# Python one print command two variables output two diffent lines to screen

Tags: php, python, linux, newline, python-2.6

I have a php script accesible via Apache which calls a python script to cat /etc/redhat-release on two servers and return the results and assign them as two different variables.  I then print the two variables to screen.  The problem is that it prints them on the same line on the screen:  ['Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)\n', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)\n']

I've tried inserting a \n or "\n" in between the to but I get an error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
File "/var/www/html/php/check_version.py", line 35
  print first + \n second
                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

If I print them on two lines it only gives me the last variable.  For example:

```
print first
print second ( I only get this result on the screen )
```

What am I missing?

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko, os, string, threading
import getpass
import socket
import sys

firsthost = '192.168.1.4'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(firsthost, username='user', password='password')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat /etc/redhat-release')

first = stdout.readlines()

secondhost = '192.168.1.5'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(secondhost, username='user', password='password')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat /etc/redhat-release')

second = stdout.readlines()

print first + second

ssh.close()
```

Comment: added python-2.6 tag, removed variables tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** You're currently using the following commands to extract the information from stdout:

```
first = stdout.readlines()
second = stdout.readlines()
```

This will return a list and in turn when you add them together will print out a list. You don't want that. You want them to be strings (it's also a good idea to strip them on excessive newlines) so you'd want to do the following:

```
first = stdout.readline().strip()
second = stdout.readline().strip()
```

From there you can echo them out to html with a tag to separate the lines:

```
print "{0}</br>{1}".format(first,second)
```

However, if you are having problems getting valid output (as you have said in numerous comments) you might want to run the script manually before the php interface to determine that it works at all. Have it simply print the variables out, if it can't then you have a problem with your ssh exec_command.

Comment: Bob, your suggestion worked by doing two things:  1. I added your print statement and 2.  I noticed your variable does not have the s in stdout.readlines like mine did.  I removed the s and it worked. With the s it gave me no output and the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/php/check_version.py", line 18, in <module>
    first = stdout.readlines().strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip.  Problem solved.  Thank you!!

Comment: Yup, because readlines() returns a list, you want a string. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `+` (to concatenate the strings) and the quotation marks around '\n' (to make it a string):

```
>>> print 'a' + '\n' + 'b'
a
b
```

I prefer `format` though:

```
>>> print 'a{}b'.format('\n')
a
b
```

Edit: As @Bob said, in your older Python version you need to issue

```
'a{0}b'.format('\n')
```

The first snippet is working fine for me in 2.6.

Comment: Depending on python version it might be wise to mention that `"a{0}b".format("\n")` might be necessary. Or you can simply go with `"a%sb" % "\n"` which would cover more versions.

Comment: Thanks for the note, Bob. I was not aware of that. I tested the `{}`-version in Python2.7 and 3.3 and I worked fine in both.

Comment: The first option only prints the letter b.

Comment: @gineraso which python version are you using?

Comment: Python version is Python 2.6.6

Comment: I'm running this via a php web page.

Comment: @gineraso you should probably upgrade for security reasons: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/

Comment: If you're returning the result straight to html you will need a "</br>" not a "\n" FYI. Also you are reading the stdout with readlines() which returns a list not a string, thus this wouldn't work.

Comment: I tried the </br> but I get this error:  
  File "/var/www/html/php/check_version.py", line 32
    print first  "</br>" + second
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I just tested the first version in python2.6 and it works fine. Also, the `{0}` format seems to be necessary.

Comment: @gineraso you need to issue `'a{0}b'.format('\n')` (notice the `0`) in Python2.6. I was not aware of that, as it is not necessary in 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: I get no results when issuing: 'first{0}second'.format('\n')

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `\n` in quotes. Also it is a string literal, so you need to concatenate `first`, `"\n"`, and `second` together to make one string to print.

```
print first + "\n" + second
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `+`'s between `first` and `second`. To fix your example, do:

```
`print first + '\n' + second`
```

Or you can do a format string like the below: (my preference)

```
first = 'foo'
second = 'bar'
print '%s\n%s' % (first, second)

# foo
# bar
```

Comment: This only prints the second variable to the screen.

Comment: print out `first` and nothing else. Is it blank? It could be that nothing is being piped into stdout..

Comment: It prints out the first variable: ['Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)\n']

Comment: Uh, it might be doing something weird because it's a list. try `print '%s\n%s' % (first[0], second)`

Comment: Print only second variable to screen:  ['Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)\n']

Comment: I'm confused. Both the first and second are the same value? `print 'first: %s' % len(first)` and `print 'second: %s' % len(second)`

Comment: No, it's two different results.  First = 6.5 and Second =  6.2.  Here's what I get if I simply use print first + second    ['Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)\n', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)\n']

Comment: OK they're both lists and you're adding them so it makes one giant list. `print first[0], second[0].strip()`

Comment: Still only get the second variable.

Comment: I don't know what else I can do to help :)

Comment: Just to be clear, when I run your command via the command line it works:  # python check_version.py
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago) it's via the php web page that it only displays the second variable.

Comment: No worries.  I certainly appreciate the effort and suggestions.  I've been battling this all day.  :/

Comment: Try breaking it apart on two print statements? I don't work with php much, but make it as simple as possible and see if that works. Then make it cleaner.

Comment: I tried that but it only prints the second variable.

Comment: Reverse the order of the variables, maybe it always only prints the last thing you tell it to print? Haha. I'm just guessing at stuff here.

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing.  It will display the last print variable which is why it works with one print statement as in: print first + second....unfortunately it comes out on the same line.

Comment: I mean you should probably figure out why it's doing that on the php side. But.. `new = first[0] + second[0].strip()` and `print new`

Comment: Bob found a solution.  See above.  Thanks for your help.